# how to check in datagrid wpf if item exists or no in a certain column (in a certain property)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net, datagrid

Question 1 :

i have a code like this

```
Public TheList As New List(Of Server)
```

the server class contains a property called "ID"
i want to search if the list contains an item with the "ID" property (integer)
how can i do such a thing ?

Question 2 :

i have a datagrid with the property Itemssource set to {Binding TheList} will it auto update the list and the UI to show the new added items to "TheList" or no ?
if no how can i make it update ?

answer in c# or vb
thanks .

Comment: for the question 1 : I don't understand, do you have a list of objects and want to check if they have an "ID" property or what ?

Comment: i have a list of objects (the objects = a class called Server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q1: `TheList.Find(Function(x) x.ID = 1234)`

Q2: Instead of a list you could better use an `ObservableCollection` instead of `List`. `ObservableCollection` does the notification automatically. Not sure if you could substitute it in your code, but it might be worth to try. So probably use: `ObservableCollection(Of Server)` instead of `List(Of Server)`. At least, `List` will not do the notification automatically.